# Errors in html anchor tag

Tags: html, anchor

I took a break from web development for a bit and now I've come up with an error.
As an example, I want to make a link to Google and I'm not sure why the code below does not work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Refresher</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <a href="www.google.com"> Google </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

The resulting error was: File not found "Firefox can’t find the file at /C:/Users/John/www.google.com."

Comment: "I've come up with an error" — **What** error?

Comment: "I'm not sure why this code below doesn't work" — You forgot the `https://` in the URL

Comment: "My question is which files require these CSP headers (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) also, where in the file do I place these headers such as (in the head section, as part of a meta tag?" — See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview for an explanation of HTTP headers.

Comment: "I remember an announcement from Google sometime in the past year or so that said it was becoming compulsory" — It isn't (except perhaps to access certain APIs and you aren't accessing *any* APIs)

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for the help it seems I was missing "https://" in the anchor tag

Comment: @Quentin Also, out of curiousity do you know why missing a https:// in the anchor tag would stop the website from loading properly?

Comment: Because a relative link to `http://example.com/your-previous-page/www.google.com` is a different URL to `https://www.google.com/`

Comment: @Quentin And apologies, you're right CSP has nothing to do with this question I think I may have to change the title, I falsely attributed it to CSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `https://` in the url before `www` in anchor tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Refresher</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <a href="https://www.google.com"> Google </a>
  </body>
</html>
```